# Python text spacing and aligning while fetching webpages via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

I am trying to implement a basic python web crawling script using beautifulsoup4 (Pyhton3.4). It is used to fetch the current 'league standings' of the National Basketball Association (NBA-Reg Season).

I was trying to make the text look in a more '**tabular**' way but unable to do so. Example:

```
Golden State Warriors  67  7  0.905  40-5
San Antonio Spurs      62 12  0.838  39-6
```

Instead, it appears like this (deranged..kind of manner)

```
Golden State Warriors  67  7  0.905  40-5
San Antonio Spurs  62  12  0.838  39-6
```

I've tried working with `string.format()` but to no avail.

Here's a my code snippet used to extract the data from the webpage:

```
for row in tableStats.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    print("\n")
    row_team = row.find_all("td")

    try:
        for stat in row_team:
            print("{0:>5} {1:>5} ".format(stat.text," "), end=" ")
            f.write("{0:^2} {1:^3} ".format(stat.text," "))
        if(i == 16 and flag == 0):
            i = int("0")
            flag = int('1')
            print("\n\n\n\n")
            print("Western Conference".center(10),"\n\n\n")
            f.write("Western Conference\n\n")

        i = i + 1
        f.write("\n")
    except Exception as e:   #In Case a none object gets returned
        pass
```

Suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Maybe there's extra whitespace at the end of these elements? Can you try calling `strip()` for each element you retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

as you're not giving a reproducible example, I'll just go on with a few advices, and all code below has been untested, so it's to be considered for the *algorithmic idea*, not a direct copy/paste.

You have two strategies to nail this problem:

1. you're setting ahead from parsing the width of each column ;
2. you're getting the size of each column based on the largest cell.

### Strategy ①: single pass, but fixed header column width

For the first strategy you can do it in one loop (as you're doing), but you need a way to treat differently the first cell of a row from the others, so you can give it a larger size. So that would be:

```
### within your try/except block:
# take the first cell to show off the team name on 20 columns
# and strip it if it's longer than 20 columns. I like to add
# three dots to strings I'm cutting, so here it goes:
if len(row_team[0]) > 20:
    out_l = ['{}…'.format(row_team[0][:19])]
else:
    # the ljust() method pads the right side of your string 
    # with spaces 
    out_l = [row_team[0].ljust(20)]
for stat in row_team[1:]:
    # for each stat, parse it as float, and reinterpret it so
    # it's a ' 0.00' format, you might want to do 5.2f if some
    # values are in the 100s
    out_l.append("{: 4.2f}".format(float(stat)))

# printing out the line, by making a string out of the list
# using the ' '.join() method, adding a single space between
# elements
out = ' '.join(out_l)
print(out)
# write the line with a carriage return
f.write('{}\n'.format(out))

if(i == 16 and flag == 0):
    # here I'm centering the string's middle at 40 columns
    # considering a full width of 80 columns. If you set 10
    # columns for a string that's 18 characters, it's going
    # to have no effects!
    out = "Western Conference".center(80)
    print() # empty line
    print(out)
    print() # empty line
    # print the string surrounded by empty lines
    f.write("\n{}\n\n".format(out))
```

BTW, to avoid having to manage `i` as:

```
i = 0
for whatever:
    something
    i = i + 1
```

you can do:

```
for i, row in enumerate(tableStats.find_all('tr')[2:]):
```

and i will be incremented for each value. Which would give you an output like:

```
Golden State Warrio… 67.00  7.00 0.90 40-05
San Antonio Spurs    62.00 12.00 0.83 39-06
                                      ^^^^^- this is not handled with
                                             the code above, cf the end
                                             of my post.
```

### strategy ②: with two passes

For the second strategy, you need to build a matrix (so basically a list of lists), as a first pass:

```
# init the matrix as an empty list
stats_matrix = []
for row in tableStats.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    row_team = row.find_all("td")
    # build a list, starting with the first cell:
    line = [row_team[0]]
    # find out what's the largest string for the first column
    max_header_size = max(max_header_size, len(row_team[0])
    for stat in row_team[1:]:
        # then all the other cells as floats
        line.append(float(stat))
    # add it to the matrix:
    stats_matrix.append(line)
```

then once it's done, you can use the `max_header_size` to format your first column:

```
for line in stats_matrix:
    # show the first cell with a padding on the right of size "max_header_size"
    out = [line[0].ljust(max_header_size)]
    for stat in line[1:]:
        # print each stat, which was stored as float, as a ' 0.00' string
        out.append("{: 4.2f}".format(stat))
    # show on standard output
    print(' '.join(line))
    # and write to file (with extra \n at the end)
    f.write('{}\n'.format(' '.join(line)))
```

and then you should see it all well formatted.

N.B.: all that being said, this code won't work with your data set, as the last value is *NOT* a float, but a score (`NN-NN`). So it's up to you to fix it so the last element is not being taken as a float.

If I were you, I'd consider this option (for the second strategy):

```
…
# iterate over the stats, leaving out the first and last value
for stat in line[1:-1]:
    # do stuff with the floats
score = line[-1].split('-') # split the string in two values
line.append(score) # store the value as a tuple
```

and then within the second loop:

```
…
for stat in line[1:-1]:
    …
line.append('{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(score[0], score[1]))
# show on standard output
print(' '.join(line))
…
```

Then you should have an output like:

```
Golden State Warriors 67.00  7.00 0.90 40-05
San Antonio Spurs     62.00 12.00 0.83 39-06
```

HTH